# Is it possible to use Android TV as a second monitor wirelessly with Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, android

I have a motorola zx pro Android TV with version 10.

I want to use it as second monitor.

Is it possible in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This isn't exactly using the TV as a second monitor but you can control your Ubuntu system from the TV this way. This answer requires your computer to be working so that your monitor (TV) can display the screen**

---

Yes it is possible. I guess it will work in your case, but it will be kinda slow.

On the Android television download Anydesk from Play store.

Then, on Ubuntu download AnyDesk using Software Center or

Through GUI: go to https://anydesk.com/platforms select your os-compatibility version and install through Ubuntu Software Center.

Through CLI:

`sudo dpkg -i anydesk_2.9.4-1_amd64.deb` Install AnyDesk via Ubuntu software center. (Simply open your 'Downloads' folder, right click on anydesk_2.9.4-1_amd64.deb choose Open With Software Install. Enter your password when it prompted then wait for the AnyDesk installation process to complete.)

Then download AnyDesk Control Plugin using Software Center in Ubuntu if you find it (it is available for only some releases so if you don't get it then it's OK it is not necessary)

Then download AnyDesk Control Plugin on your television using Play store. It is necessary to download in order to control your computer using the television.

90% of your work is done.

Now open AnyDesk on the television and enable the plugin following the on screen steps.

I hope you have a wireless or wired mouse and keyboard connected to television in order to control your computer using the television.

Now open AnyDesk on your Ubuntu

Then enter the up code you see in red where it says connect to remotely, e.g. `123 456 789`, whatever number it is showing on the laptop enter it.

Now accept all warnings **do this at your own risk though AnyDesk is trusted but still take some precautions**.

You will see screen of Ubuntu on your television.

Now control using your input devices ie - mouse and keyboard

Hope this works :)

**If you want exact monitor ie exactly as we buy one from store then follow these steps instead.**

**Note - Do everything at your own risk**

You need an **HDMI** cable for this.
Just buy one of good quality.

Attach one side of hdmi with tv and one with your CPU.

Then just turn on everything. Open your tv go to input sources or live tv app and select **HDMI PORT** where you attached the cable.

This will show the display on tv now control it using mouse and keyboard attached to **CPU**

I hope my answer will help you

Comment: Although AnyDesk is available for Linux and free to download, so your recommendation to use it seems likely to be helpful, I can't see an `anydesk` package for any supported version of Ubuntu, so I don't think `sudo apt install anydesk` will work. I'm using Lubuntu, so I'm not able to look for it in Ubuntu Software Center, but I would be surprised if it is there - is that where you installed it from? Maybe check and adjust the installation instructions, or you can correct me...

Comment: right, so we need to download the file first - would you mind making an [edit] your answer to make it more clear about this?

Comment: sorry for being unclear - I am not having this problem myself - I'm just trying to help you improve the answer! At the moment I think your answer is partly not right because it suggests `sudo apt install anydesk` which, I think, will not work because there is no such package. So I am suggesting you [edit] your answer and remove that, and instead add the instructions to download the deb file from the correct website and install it as you mentioned. BTW Lubuntu comes with Discover app, but I don't find anything when I search for AnyDesk. I think one must download AnyDesk from their website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130250/discussion-between-akshaj-singla-and-zanna).